# Select polygons with 5 or more points

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have two layers (polygon and point) in QGIS added from PostgreSQL database and want to select polygons from index grid with 5 or more points on them.
Is this possible to do in QGIS or in PgAdmin?

here is an example photo:

[image]

Comment: If any of the answers fills your need, please mark it as "accepted": it will help other users. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 16):

In QGIS you can conveniently use the `Edit` -> `Select` -> `Select Features by Expression` command:

[image]

With an expression like this:

```
aggregate('Random points', 'count','', contains(geometry(@parent),$geometry))>=5
```

Where:

- `aggregate` is the function used to calculate the number of points contained in each polygon
- `Random points` is the name of the point layer
- `count` is the `aggregation` type
- `''` is the (empty) `aggregate` "expression"
- `contains(geometry(@parent),$geometry)`is the `aggregate` filter specifying you want to count only points contained in each feature of the "parent" layer (in this case, the polygon layer)

[image]

Only polygons containing at least (`>=`) 5 points are selected.

Answer (score 10):

The equivalent SQL (PostgreSQL/PostGIS & SpatiaLite [i.e. QGIS *Virtual Layers*]) would be:

```
SELECT  a.<id>
        a.<geom>
FROM    poly AS a
JOIN    pts AS b
  ON    ST_Intersects(a.<geom>, b.<geom>)
GROUP BY
        a.<id>, a.<geom>
HAVING  COUNT(b.<id>) >= 5
;
```

Make sure you have a spatial index in place. Note that any additional column from `poly` mentioned in the `SELECT` list (i.e. `a.<column>`) needs to appear in the `GROUP BY`, if there is no unique (primary) key present in the table to base the grouping on.

---

In case your grid is regular and its cells strictly square, you can use (PostgreSQL/PostGIS only):

```
SELECT  a.<id>
        a.<geom>
FROM    poly AS a
JOIN    pts AS b
  ON    a.<geom> && b.<geom>
GROUP BY
        a.<id>, a.<geom>
HAVING  COUNT(b.<id>) >= 5
;
```

to avoid the intersection test on the geometry components. This might be useful for very large tables.

Comment: Just changed to using `HAVING`; wasn't sure *SQLite* supports it, but it does.

Comment: If you go the virtual layer way (SpatialLite), you can keep any field from the polygon layer and simply do `group by a.id`, as it is the PK and the "1st" (and only!) matching row will be returned.